# Visual Basic Editor Help for Excel 2011 Mac version is in .chm format

Tags: excel, macos, vba, chm

I am using Excel 2011 on an iMac and trying to develop VBA macros.  The help files are inadequate so I have gone to Microsoft's download area for the Visual Basic Editor Help file.  This is in .chm formate which can't be opened on a Mac.  Where do I get help?  The book I am following says "place the cursor on the word I want to look up and press "F1" - this doesn't work either!

Comment: You probably won't get any relevant answers. Your question doesn't state your issue. Opening a file isn't a stackoverflow topic. Consider reading the FAQ's articles.

Comment: My question is how do I get Help support for VBA using Excel 2011 on an iMac?  The only help that loads when I ask for it is related to the day to day use of Excel but not macro work.  On my old Windows system I had all the help I needed!  Sorry if the Headline wasn't clear but the text was - I thought.

Comment: Clearly one solution is to install Windows :-) Another is to search for a CHM helpviewer. There are some in the Linux camp, maybe there are some for Mac too. Search for Gnochm, kchmviewer and xchm in combintation with Mac.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the answer you want, but you can look up VBA objects, properties and methods in this section on MSDN:
[Excel developer reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee861528(v=office.15).aspx)

(At least in Windows, the local VBA help file is a copy of this MSDN section.)

You can use your favourite search engine to look up stuff on MSDN:

```
activecell site:msdn.microsoft.com
```

Comment: Thanks for that info.  I don't have a MSDN account (overkill) and the Excel developer reference link leads to Excel 2013 only.  The bottom line is that Microsoft never provided a reference tailored for Mac users and much of what is written in books based on Windows VBA is not useable on the Mac (shortcuts and F keys for example).  I can't even read the .chm file on Excel 2013! without downloading third party software.